# Webpart custom property is not saving in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, custom-properties

My custom property is declared like every example out there:

```
    [WebBrowsable(true)]
    [WebDisplayName("Group By Date")]
    [Description("Group Articles by date")]
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    [Category("Extended Settings")]
    public bool GroupByDate
    {
        get { return _groupByDate; }
        set { _groupByDate = value; }
    }
```

The control is databinding it:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AnotherTestPart.ascx.cs" Inherits="FeatureElements.WebParts.AnotherTestPart.AnotherTestPart" %>
<div><%: GroupByDate %></div>
```

It displays in the edit region:

[image: Displays in the Edit region]
I have added the custom property to the .webpart file and removed it and neither variation makes a difference.

[image]

Why won't this webpart persist the custom property value? 
Do I need to have this value present on a list on the site? 
Is there an event I need to wire the property up to?
Is there a Sharepoint setting that could be blocking custom property persistence?

Comment: The property means the custom property code you added to .webpart file?

Comment: yes. I'll update the description.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this It will may help you

```
 [WebBrowsable(true), 
   Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User), 
   WebDescription("Group Articles by date"),
   Category("Extended Settings"), 
   WebDisplayName("Group By Date")]
   public bool GroupByDate
   {
       get { return _groupByDate; }
       set { _groupByDate = value; }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I want the property set for all users. Not per user.

Comment: Did you try adding DefaultValue attribute?

Comment: If I add a DefaultValue attribute and initialize it in the constructor, it does set the value. However, changing the value in the edit part does NOT persist the change.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. If anyone has another idea regarding webpart deployment or maybe sharepoint configuration, I'd be all ears. Seems like I'm doing this properly from a code standpoint.